# One private key for two wallet problem - How can I get bitcoin hard fork?

Tags: blockchain-fork

I have a wallet named w1 which has the united bitcoin already (I checked on the block explorer)
When I extract w1's private key and put into the united bitcoin desktop wallet, it points to a different wallet w2. This w2 does not have any hard forked coin.

My question is: How can I let the desktop wallet know I want it point the address to w1, not w2 ?

Comment: which wallet did you use? many wallet-softwares are using several private keys to improve your privacy. maybe you just used a "wrong" of the private keys of your wallet?

Comment: I used airbit. My private key is not wrong, it is used for two different wallet (maybe more). Anyway, I used a trick to make ubtc wallet accept my w2 instead of w1 on the initial scan. So after adding my private key, I succeeded to get my ubtc.